# How to send multiple ids to another page from selected checboxes using a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On the first page, if a person selects multiple values, he will display the selected values. Then, he will click the button that will link to the second page. Where the button holds the selected values for the second page.

The selected values will be held and the second page will need to select them again. The first page has checkboxes, the second page has something like a radio button. But it was a link that holds the ids.

Once the value for the first and second page is on hold, it will go to the database to check the values for each page. If the values are in the database, it will display the information based on the first and second page values.

First page(menu.php)

```
   <?php        
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         if(!empty($_POST['penyakit'])) {
             // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
             $checked_count = count($_POST['penyakit']);
             echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
             // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
             foreach($_POST['penyakit'] as $selected) {
                        echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>"; 
             }
            }
            // echo "<a href='menu0.php?penyakit={$selected}' class='btn 
              btn-primary left-margin'>";
            //echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> Baca";
             // echo "</a>";
           }
         else{
             echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
         } 

    ?>
```

Second page(menu0.php)

```
$selected = isset($_GET['selected']) ? $_GET['selected'] : die('ERROR: missing ID.');
<table class="table">
             <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr>
                      <div class="container">
                        <center><a class="list-unstyled-item list-hours-item d-flex" href='bfasM.php?selected={$selected}'><img border="0" src="img/bfas.jpg" width="250" height="100" ></a>
                        <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                        <span class="section-heading-upper">Sarapan Pagi </span>
                        </h2></center>
                      </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="container">
                        <center><a class="list-unstyled-item list-hours-item d-flex" href="lunchM.php?selected={$selected}"><img border="0" src="img/lunch.jpg" width="250" height="100" ></a>
                        <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                        <span class="section-heading-upper">Makan Tengah Hari </span>
                        </h2></center>
                      </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="container">
                        <center><a class="list-unstyled-item list-hours-item d-flex" href="snackM.php?selected={$selected}"><img border="0" src="img/dinner.jpeg" width="250" height="100" ></a><h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                        <span class="section-heading-upper">Snack </span>
                        </h2></center>
                      </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="container">
                        <center><a class="list-unstyled-item list-hours-item d-flex" href="dinnerM.php?selected={$selected}"><img border="0" src="img/snack.jpg" width="250" height="100" ></a><h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                        <span class="section-heading-upper">Makan malam </span>
                        </h2></center>
                      </div>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
              </table>
```

Third page (bfasM.php)
On this page I want to display based on what they have choose in first page and second page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issues. Maybe you could split yout questions into simple steps. For example: 1. get values from checkboxes. 2. Set radio buttons based on the previews step's values .etc. This way will much easier for us to help you. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: yess iwould like to do that. but idont know how

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the second page? Following  your question, the user can select multiple values in the first page (because it's checkboxes) and only one value in the second? Also, do you have to do this in php? Because you can do this with javascript..